# showing the checked item alone without check box

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

forms.py

```
PERSON_ACTIONS = (
    ('1', '01.Allowed to rest and returned to class'),
    ('2', '02.Contacted parents /guardians'),
    ('3', '02a.- Unable to Contact'),
    ('4', '02b.Unavailable - left message'),)

class PersonActionsForm(forms.ModelForm):
   action = forms.MultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(), choices=PERSON_ACTIONS, required=False, label= u"Actions")
```

models.py

```
class Actions(models.Model):
    report = models.ForeignKey(Report)
    action =  models.IntegerField('Action type')
```

print.html

```
{{ actionform.as_p}}
```

The PersonActionsForm contains the items with multichoice checkbox.
In report registration page,the  user can select any one or more item.The checked items are saved in models as integer values.

Since i am rendering the whole form it is showing the entire form with checked and unchecked item.

In print page,i want to show only the checked item alone without checkbox.

How to do this in django.

Thanks

Comment: Any update on this question.

Comment: why not just use css to control this ? Hide everything which is not checked and show just the checked ones

Comment: @karthikr,the choices are from the django form,in db the values of the checked items get saved and not the description(like int).Is it possible to do it using css.

Comment: Yeah.. you can detect it using jquery, and add a css class or just remove those nodes. Im not saying this is the cleanest way though

Comment: It will be easy for me if you post me a sample link.

Comment: [Check this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3312502/hide-text-when-checkbox-is-unchecked-using-jquery)

Comment: @karthikr,in my case,i need to hide the name of the check box but in that post it is for hiding the div data

Comment: The aim of this question is to display the checked item in human readable format,see my models and forms.py

Comment: If I understand correctly and you simply want to show the *selected* item, eg "02a. - Unable to Contact" then you probably want a method on your model which looks `obj.action` up in the `PERSON_ACTIONS` list (I'd probably `zip` the latter to make a dictionary). Don't use forms if you're not doing form actions with them.

Comment: @JamesAylett,You got the point what i required,in registration page i am getting the input through the same form,and for displaying purpose i can set in models.Any solution please post.

Comment: Done; my apologies for saying `zip` in my earlier comment without thinking it through. You just need `dict` for this, as given in my answer.

Comment: The aim of this question is to display the checked item in human readable format,like eg "02a. - Unable to Contact" need help to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on James's answer. You can move `PERSON_ACTIONS` to your model and import it in form.

models.py:

```
PERSON_ACTIONS = (
    ('1', '01.Allowed to rest and returned to class'),
    ('2', '02.Contacted parents /guardians'),
    ('3', '02a.- Unable to Contact'),
    ('4', '02b.Unavailable - left message'),
)
PERSON_ACTIONS_DICT = dict(PERSON_ACTIONS)

class Actions(models.Model):
    report = models.ForeignKey(Report)
    action =  models.IntegerField('Action type')

    def action_as_text(self):
        return PERSON_ACTIONS_DICT.get(str(self.action), None)
```

forms.py:

```
from .models import PERSON_ACTIONS

class PersonActionsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    action = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
        widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(), 
        choices=PERSON_ACTIONS, 
        required=False, 
        label= u"Actions"
    )
```

Get the actions in `views.py`:

```
actions = Actions.objects.filter(....)
return render(request, 'your_template.html', {
    .....
    'actions': actions   
})
```

... and render it in template:

```
{% for action in actions %}
    {{ action.action_as_text }}
{% endfor %}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried with manually inserting the froms choice into models an tried ,it is not showing the checked items

Comment: Hmm could you add how did you print out the result with view + template code?

Comment: Exactly what I think, that `obj` should be the action object passed from `views.py`. Please check https://gist.github.com/H25/cc0d50541ed824fb52aa

Comment: Hey, did you actually pass the `action` object in `views.py`? Could you do `{{ action }}` in template to debug?

Comment: yes ,i got the db object like this [<Actions: Actions object>, <Actions: Actions object>].

Comment: I see, since your queryset returns list, you need to loop it in template. Check my edited answer.

Comment: @HieuNguyen Is it possible to check my SO question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18592136/add-image-to-all-check-box-django please

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be using forms for non-edit display purposes. Instead, make a method on your class:

```
from forms import PERSON_ACTIONS
PERSON_ACTIONS_DICT = dict(PERSON_ACTIONS)

class Actions(models.Model):
    report = models.ForeignKey(Report)
    action =  models.IntegerField('Action type')

    def action_as_text(self):
        return PERSON_ACTIONS_DICT.get(str(self.action), None)
```

Then you can just do `{{ obj.action_as_text }}` in a template and get the text you want. Note that it would probably be more common to use integers in the `PERSON_ACTIONS` array (then you don't need the `str` call in `action_as_text`.)

Comment: from forms import PERSON_ACTIONS and 
PERSON_ACTIONS_DICT = dict(PERSON_ACTIONS)  the above two lines make the above error.It is stopping the server.I updated the traceback happened in console.

Comment: Aargh, circular references. Without knowing more about your code, try moving the `dict(PERSON_ACTIONS)` inside `action_as_text` and drop the import to the bottom of the file. It's not the most efficient approach, but it should work. Or more `PERSON_ACTIONS` into another module so you can import it without pulling in all of `incident.forms`.

Comment: @JamesAylett Can you please have a look at this SO question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18592136/add-image-to-all-check-box-django